# Why my carousel from Bootstrap Examples page not working?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I am doing a web page with Bootstrap, and I want to add a carousel. So I went to the Examples page, and looked for the source code of the carousel template (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/examples/carousel/). I copy/paste the carousel section into my web page but it is not working.

[carousel from bootsrap web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dU2DS.png)

[carousel from my web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxB9s.png)

As you can see, I got a tiny portion of the original carousel, and I don't know why, because it is supposed to be the original source code of the carousel of Bootstrap. Here the portion of my code related to the carousel :

```
 <body>
    <?php include "header.php" ?>
    <main role="main">
     <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"/></svg>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
            <h1>Example headline.</h1>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"/></svg>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"/></svg>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption text-right">
            <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: have you added any script???

Comment: Yes I added 3 scripts : <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/csscode.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="..." crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/... .js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: see my answer, I have added the scripts which you have missed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use jquery and bootstrap bundle plugin and also add custom CSS.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/examples/carousel/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body>
    <main role="main">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid
                    slice" focusable="false" role="img">
                    <rect width="100%" height="100%"
                        fill="#777"/>
                </svg>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
                        <h1>Example headline.</h1>
                        <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id
                            dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
                        </p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid
                    slice" focusable="false" role="img">
                    <rect width="100%" height="100%"
                        fill="#777"/>
                </svg>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
                        <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id
                            dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
                        </p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid
                    slice" focusable="false" role="img">
                    <rect width="100%" height="100%"
                        fill="#777"/>
                </svg>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption text-right">
                        <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>           
                        <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id
                            dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
                        </p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>   
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding jquery plugin and bootstrap js just the end of your HTML body tag. You forgot to add jquery and bootstrap js, without adding this carousel won't work. As you said you copied and pasted from that example, so I think you also forgot to add their custom CSS

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" hre="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/examples/carousel/carousel.css">
```

Comment: I still got the tiny portion of the original carousel. But at least with your scripts now my carousel can switch between slides when I click on the next/previous buttons, whereas it didn't work before. Thanks.

Comment: because you were missed to add jquery and bootstrap js, without those it won't work

Comment: I edited my answer, you can again copy and paste those codes

Comment: I copied the last link but I still got the tiny portion of the carousel.

Comment: see my latest answer, I have added another answer

Comment: I did it but I got : "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." Sorry haha.

Comment: @PharaohOfParis haha